Issues Establishing CAN FD on STM32U575
I'm trying to establish CAN FD communication using the STM32U575 microcontroller, but I've encountered some difficulties. While I successfully set up loop-back mode using the HAL library, I keep receiving HAL_ERROR from HAL_FDCAN_Start(&hfdcan1) despite the message transmitting successfully.
I've also reviewed this resource: STM32 FDCAN Communication: How do you set up FDCAN using low level programming on STM32U5? and attempted to implement the configuration using low-level (LL) programming instead of HAL. However, I'm still unable to achieve communication.
It appears that there are no open-source projects specific to the STM32U575 that I can reference.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If it works in loopback mode but not in real-world mode, that likely means a hardware problem. The most common problem by far is the lack of a second node to ACK the message. What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?
